# How to print XSLT version supported by Xalan in Xalan c++?

Tags: xalan

I am using Xalan C++ library and I want to print the XSL version supported by it.
How to print XSLT version supported by Xalan in Xalan c++?

Is there is any api/function in xalan which can return the version of XSL supported by Xalan?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-system-property, you should be able to use e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>
```

with any XSLT processor.

Comment: This will print in the xsl output. But i want to know whether there is any api/funtion in xalan which can return the version of XSL supported by xalan.

Comment: I see, you might want to remove the `xslt` tag from your post then as that sounds as if you are looking for XSLT code.